# How to set each List's Command component so that there is no space between the containing Dialog and the Command's texts?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

There is a Dialog which contains a List of Commands. When shown then the Label renderer of the `public Component getListFocusComponent(List list)` method and the Component of the `public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected)` method of the derived class `DefaultListCellRenderer` are not occupying all of the width of the Dialog.

So how to make the Label and the selection-component occupy all the width of the containing Dialog ?

Here is the code :

```
public class CMenu extends Dialog {
    private String disp;
    private List lCmds;
    public static Command retCommand;
    public CMenu(Command[] cmds, String disposition)
    {
        super();
        this.getStyle().setBorder(Border.createRoundBorder(10, 20));
        afficheCmd(cmds);
        this.setScrollableY(false);
        disp = disposition;
    }
    private void afficheCmd(Command[] cmds)
    {
        lCmds = new List(cmds);
        lCmds.setListCellRenderer(new TickerRenderer());
        lCmds.setCommandList(true);
        lCmds.setPreferredW(this.getPreferredW());
        lCmds.setFixedSelection(List.FIXED_NONE_CYCLIC);
        ((DefaultListCellRenderer)lCmds.getRenderer()).setShowNumbers(false);
        this.addComponent(lCmds);
        lCmds.setSelectedIndex(0);
        lCmds.requestFocus();
    }
    protected void onShow()
    {
        lCmds.setSelectedIndex(0);
        lCmds.requestFocus();
    }
    public void affiche()
    {
        int top = Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight() - lCmds.getHeight();
        if (disp.equalsIgnoreCase("gauche"))
        {
            this.show(top, 0, 0, 100, false);
        }
        else
        {
            this.show(top, 0, 100, 0, false);
        }
        lCmds.requestFocus();
        lCmds.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }
    protected void actionCommand(Command cmd)
    {
        retCommand = cmd;
        this.dispose();
    }
}

class TickerRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    private DefaultListCellRenderer selectedRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer(false);
    private List parentList;

    public TickerRenderer() {
        super(false);
    }

    public boolean animate() {
        if (parentList != null && parentList.getComponentForm() != null) {
            if (selectedRenderer.isTickerRunning()) {
                if (selectedRenderer.animate()) {
                    parentList.repaint();
                }
            }
        }
        return super.animate();
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected)
    {
        if (isSelected)
        {
            (selectedRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected)).getSelectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
            (selectedRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected)).getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);

            (selectedRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected)).getSelectedStyle().setFgColor(16777215);
            (selectedRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected)).getUnselectedStyle().setFgColor(0);

            if (index == list.getSelectedIndex())
            {
                if (selectedRenderer.shouldTickerStart())
                {
                    if (!selectedRenderer.isTickerRunning())
                    {
                        parentList = list;
                        list.getComponentForm().registerAnimated(this);
                        selectedRenderer.startTicker(UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel().getTickerSpeed(), true);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (selectedRenderer.isTickerRunning())
                    {
                        selectedRenderer.stopTicker();
                    }
                }
            }
            return selectedRenderer;
        }
        else
        {
            return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected);
        }
    }
    public Component getListFocusComponent(List list) {
        Label label = new Label("");
        label.getStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
        label.getStyle().setBgColor(205388);
        label.getStyle().setBorder(Border.createRoundBorder(5, 10, 16777215));
        return label;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , here it is :

```
lCmds.getSelectedStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
lCmds.getUnselectedStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
this.getContentPane().getSelectedStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
this.getContentPane().getUnselectedStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
this.addComponent(lCmds);
```